# Typescript async generator compilation/type issues

Tags: typescript, async-await, generator

I'm having trouble getting Webstorm to be happy with an async generator I'm trying to write. The idea is to read data from Elastic Search and send it over a Node stream. Here is the code and then I'll post the errors below:

```
let resultsSent = 0;
let response: SearchResponse<any> = await client.search(query);
async function* resultGenerator(sr: SearchResponse<any>): Promise<IteratorResult<any>> {
    for (let hit of sr.hits.hits) {
        yield hit;
    }
    resultsSent += sr.hits.hits.length;
    console.log(`Sent ${resultsSent} results from ES to stream.`);
    if (sr.hits.total > resultsSent) {
        const params: ScrollParams = {
            scrollId: response._scroll_id,
            scroll: '60s'
        };
        response = await client.scroll(params);
        yield* resultGenerator(response);
    }
}
return new Readable({
    objectMode: true,
    async read(size: number) {
        for await (const hit of resultGenerator(response)) {
            if (!this.push(hit)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The IDE is complaining that:

1. The return type of the function is incorrect:[image: Error message on return type]
2. The yield* call is similarly incorrect because the function return type: [image: Error message on yield*]

What is the correct type for the function return or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Remove the return type annotation from the generator and reap a bounty of type information

Answer (score -1):

Adding a return type of `AsyncGenerator<any>` to the generator function definition seems to make the compiler happy. Also seems to require a tsconfig lib target of at least es2019.

Comment: Are type annotation loses the precision the language infers when you omit the return type. The typescript compiler understands the syntax for generators async generators and infers a type that is much more robust than your explicit annotation involving any

Comment: The recursive form of the generator seemed to screw up the type inferencing. AsyncGenerator<_something_> Was what I was looking for.